# an element event to display none, in an element event to display flex,

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Want to make a button to display a list of elements, and in the list, there is another button to close or display none of the lists
but I don't know why it's not working

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1');
let btn2 = document.querySelector('#btn2');
let article = document.querySelector('article');


btn1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    article.style.display = 'flex';
})


btn2.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    article.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
}

article {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}
p {
    color: red;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn1">
        <article>
            <p>hello world</p>
            <p>hello world</p>
            <p>hello world</p>
            <span id="btn2">btn2</span>
        </article>
    </div>
```

**strong text**

Comment: If you need buttons, use `<button>` element. Then it is also clear why this html structure doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @cloned yes but that's not the issue here. There are many ways in which this small code could be better but here we are just asked to solve why the event handlers are not correctly dealing with the scenario

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle thing happening in your scenario. The divs listening to the click event are nested so that the click event "bubbles" and gets propagated to the parent producing a scenario where both handlers get called for the same click -> hence your element is getting hidden and immediately after showed again.

To prevent that to happen I called `event.stopPropagation()` in the function handling the click event for the child element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

```js
let btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1');
let btn2 = document.querySelector('#btn2');
let article = document.querySelector('article');


btn1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    article.style.display = 'flex';
})


btn2.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    article.style.display = 'none';
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
div#btn1{
  border: solid 1px red;
  cursor: pointer;
}


div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    
    border: solid 1px black;
}

article {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    border: solid 1px black;
}
p {
    color: red;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*
    right: -100px;
    color: white;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="btn1">
    <article>
        <p>hello world</p>
        <p>hello world</p>
        <p>hello world</p>
        <span id="btn2">Click Here</span>
    </article>
</div>
```